# Python: Print something if none of the if statements in the function are used

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have a function that has several if statements that print "x"  if a condition:

I want to write an if statement that if none of the if statements within the function are used print "something"

reproducible example

```
def my_function(data):
    ### Constant Features Check
    x = pd.DataFrame({'value':data.nunique()})
    for col in x.index:
        if x.loc[col, 'value'] == 1:
            print('Column', col , 'is a constant value')

### lets say i have 10's of "for x in y: if statements "like this 
### If none of are activated i want to print "something"

## if none of the print statements in the for loops print, print(something')
```

Comment: Could you say something more about what the problem is you're trying to solve.  If you have 100s of `for/if` statements then something deeper is probably wrong with your approach, and it requires some more abstraction.

Comment: if you have 100s of such if statements most probably your code is in desperate need of refactoring.

Comment: I really hope you'll tell us one day why you have 100s of for loops.

Comment: @iguananaut I've re-evaluated my approach. Thank you for being so insightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print `something` if none of the `if` conditions are activated, then you can use a flag to capture if something is printed by print statements under all the if loops.

```
def my_function(data):
    ### Constant Features Check
    x = pd.DataFrame({'value':data.nunique()})
    anythingPrinted = False
    for col in x.index:
        if x.loc[col, 'value'] == 1:
            print('Column', col , 'is a constant value')
            anythingPrinted = True

    ### 100 such statements

    # At the end of the function
    if not anythingPrinted:
        print("something")
```